# Re-usable base React component bind issue with ES6

Tags: reactjs, bind, ecmascript-6

Created a base React component to inherit from:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class BaseComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    _bindProps(...methods) {
        return methods.map(method => this[method].bind(this))
    }
}

export default BaseComponent;
```

And my child component:

```
class SomeChild extends BaseComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    foo() {

    }

    render() {
        const props = this._bindProps('foo');
        <Child {...props} />
    }
}
```

However, I receive `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` on the line `return methods.map(method => this[method].bind(this))`. How can I achieve this, ie. passing down methods from a parent component to a child, and when it's called from the child, have it's `this` value reference the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class SomeChild extends BaseComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    foo = () => {

    }

    render() {
        <Child foo={this.foo} />
    }
}
```

If your just doing the BaseComponent to bind(this) to methods and using es6 it would be simpler to just use arrow functions for your methods.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that. How would I go about utilising arrow functions for this purpose? ie. passing methods down to a component

Comment: Do remember that arrow functions does not bind on the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Janaka is right about just using arrow functions, but also you've a problem with your `_bindProps` implementation. It returns an array of bound functions but you need to return a key/val object of properties. Updating your `_bindProps` definition to:

```
_bindProps(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].bind(this));
  return obj;
}
```

And calling it with an object does the trick:

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _bindProps(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k].bind(this));
    return obj;
  }
}

class SomeChild extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.name = 'Jack'
  }

  foo() {
    return this.name;
  }

  render() {
    const props = this._bindProps({
      foo: this.foo,
    });
    console.log('props', props);
    return <Child {...props} />
  }
}
```

You could tidy the above up a little but that does now do the right thing and if you call `this.props.foo()` in the child component you will get `Jack` returned back.

I'd be interested to know why you're doing this though? This isn't something I've typically had to do at any point.

Comment: I basically have two different "views" (forget MVC views, I mean literally views) for basically the same component. So I created two child components (for each "view") and then passed down all the callback methods from the 1 parent to the 2 children. The event handlers are added in the children, but they actually call methods in the parent