# How can I tell when this.setState exists in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have been struggling with trying to migrate my React code from ES5 to ES6. As I have found out by now, `this` is no longer automatically bound which causes all sorts of hell.

I am trying to figure out by trial and error what objects are being passed around. So far I can find everything and adjust accordingly. However when it comes to this.setState I am having problems because it is *not visible in console.log*!!!! See screenshot in ES5:

[image]

and here is the same kind of code in ES6:
[image]

Please teach me how to fish i.e. help me figure out how to understand when an object has this.setState or not?

things i have tried

1. from googling around i understand you might be able to [default bind everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009194/re-usable-base-react-component-bind-issue-with-es6) by changing the base component. unfortunately this did not work when it came to this.setState. It looks identical to the ES5 version of `this` in console so I concluded that setState is still not being bound somehow

Comment: Share your code here..

Comment: When you pass your component functions to event handler e.g. onClick and such, its not bind to "this". So what you have to do is something like: onClick={this.yourmethod.bind(this)}. All the other stuff , like lifecycle methods will have this in place

Comment: printing out an object with functions doesnt always work cause they can be part of the prototype. Try to debug using the browser debug tools, its much easier then doing so via console.log...

Comment: When you say "unfortunately this did not work when it came to this.setState" what does this actually mean? You're absolutely required to `.bind(this)` on event handlers if you want to preserve the scope of `this`, which does "work" in ES6.

Comment: Just define your methods with `name = () => { /* stuff /* }`, doing so the method will be auto bound to the component context

Comment: I think learning how `this` works would make your life easier in the long run, than chasing and inspecting every use of `this`. If you know how `this` works then it will be clear when and when not to bind a function.

Comment: @FezVrasta you were right. I didn't understand this.

@FelixKling yeah this is me asking for help with understanding `this`. I definitely didn't get the subtlety that when you call `this.props.method` then `this` refers to `this.props` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To oversimplify how `this` works in JS:

- If you call a function as an object method (e.g., `instance.foo()`) then `this` refers to that object instance.
- If you call a function by itself (e.g., `foo()`), then `this` is either `undefined` or the global object, depending on whether strict mode is in effect.
- If you take a reference to an object method then call it, that means you're calling it by itself, even though it was originally an object method. (E.g., `var bar = instance.foo; bar();`.

Again, this is an oversimplification; [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has details.

As this applies to React, and as explained in the React documentation on ["Handling Events"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be `undefined` when the function is actually called.

In your code, you render your `RawInput` as

```
 <RawInput value={this.state.value} updateValue={this.updateValue}/>
```

You're passing a reference `updateValue` function in as a simple function, so `this` will not be bound within `updateValue`.

Basically, any time you pass a function as a React prop, unless you've bound it yourself, it's likely an error. The symptom is typically that `this` is undefined. In your code, it's a little more complicated:

```
this.props.updateValue(modifiedValue);
```

The RawInput's `updateValue` property is the unbound function `App.updateValue`, but because you're invoking it as `this.props.updateValue`, it's being called *as if it were a method of `this.props`* - so `this` refers to the RawInput's `props`. That's why your console.log is showing an object with only two properties (`start` and `updateValue`): it isn't that `setState` isn't bound or went away, it's that `updateValue` wasn't bound, so `this` isn't what you expect within `updateValue`.

To fix the issue, as the React docs explain:

- Use a fat arrow function: `updateValue={(value) => this.updateValue(value)}`
- Use the experimental property initializer syntax: Replace `updateValue(modifiedValue) {...}` with `updateValue = (modifiedValue) => {...}`.
- Not mentioned in the React docs, but an approach I often use: Bind `updateValue` yourself. For example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Josh, I can't thank you enough. You even hunted down my pen to go in depth. just amazing. i confess I'm one of those dense people that just nods along to the docs and thinks he understands it until I actually run into the issue and I learn by sheer banging my head into a wall. thank you again. used the fat arrow. I tried a generalized binding method found somewhere else on SO (hence using BaseComponent instead of React.Component) but it did not work in this particular case probably cos of the nesting.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace console.log with this:

```
console.shallowCloneLog = function(){
    var typeString = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)
    console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(x){
        switch (typeString(x).slice(8, -1)) {
            case 'Number': case 'String': case 'Undefined': case 'Null': case 'Boolean': return x;
            case 'Array': return x.slice();
            default:
                var out = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(x));
                out.constructor = x.constructor;
                for (var key in x) {
                    out[key] = x[key];
                }
                Object.defineProperty(out, 'constructor', {value: x.constructor});
                return out;
        }
    }));
}
```

any way, regarding your question, you can add a method like this:

```
updateValue = () => {...}
```

in m POV - es6 is cool and great. React components by es6' classes are useless. stick with `createClass` and you'll be fine (and have mixins if you want!)

Comment: hey, marked Josh right as he gave an insanely comprehensive answer. this console log thing is really cool but its probably more than I need right now. Your answer was still right. Im not sure what you mean with the last part - you think es6 is cool but you dont recommend using React with es6?

Comment: I recommend using es6 in react for everything except for `classes`. greater JS developers than me also recommends that.

Comment: got it. this seems to be what codepen works best with too. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). For example:

```
var X = function() {};
X.prototype.setSomething = 'a';
var x = new X();
x.setSomething; // log 'a' here
x.hasOwnPrperty('setSomething') // log false here
```

In your case, just `console.log(this.hasOwnProperty('setState'))`.

Comment: thanks Timathon ,turns out my `this` was just plain not what i thought it was. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your `updateValue` function with the component in order to have the correct context (`this`).

In your case, your parent class `BaseComponent` allows you to use the herited method `_bind` like that :

```
class App extends BaseComponent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={value:'start'};
    this._bind('updateValue');
...
```

Comment: this... i was missing this when trying out the `BaseComponent`. thanks mr. @Freez