# unable to understand the use/need of a line of code in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and I have seen many available answers but I am unable to understand that why `this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);` is being used in the code given below? Why we cannot simply call the `setStateHandler` function on button click without this code of line written in the constructor (as we normally do in other programming languages)? Please explain in simple terminology.

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
         data: []
      }

      this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);
   };

   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState..."
      var myArray = this.state.data;
      myArray.push(item)
      this.setState({data: myArray})
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
            <h4>State Array: {this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

context aka `this` needs to be set to point to your instance **if you need to use any methods or properties**

by default, a normal DOM event handler function would use `this` as the element that triggers the event. in react+strict mode, `this` can be `undefined`, hence exception `'setState' of undefined is not a function`, unless you `bind` it to the instance or call it in an arrow function (keeping context)

so either do what you do or:

```
// arrow keeps context
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
// experimental / proposal
onClick={::this.handleClick}

// needs class properties transform, binds to instance via arrow
handleClick = event => {
  // stuff on this, then just onClick={this.handleClick}
}
```

this has to be the most common question on this tag...

keep in mind that many of the methods involve creating a new function on the fly in each `render(){}`, which comes at a performance cost - so your method is preferred or the class properties transform (which does the same)

see [How can I tell when this.setState exists in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533177/how-can-i-tell-when-this-setstate-exists-in-es6/41533969#41533969) etc